# How can I stop XPathDocument from closing the stream?

Tags: .net, xpath, stream

When calling the `XPathDocument(Stream)` constructor, the stream is automatically closed. How can I keep the stream open?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Stream`, `String` and `TextReader` overloads make use of the internal `System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl` class. [This class sets `closeInput` to `true`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextReaderImpl.cs,382).

If you want to avoid this, you need to use the `XmlReader` overload. This uses an unmodified instance of `XmlReaderSettings`, for which the default value of `CloseInput` is `false`. Don't forget to set the `Position` back to `0` afterwards.

```cs
var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
var document = new XPathDocument(reader);
stream.Position = 0;
```